# "Exception Unhandled : At least one sheet must be visible" when calling .to_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to write several sheets into the same excel file. I'm using ExcelWriter, and when I call .to_excel I get the following error: "At least one sheet must be visible". Here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```py
 pathresults = "C:/Users/SVR/SVRresults/"
 filesufix = str(_kernel)
    filenameTRpred='predicted_train_'+ filesufix + '.xlsx'
    filenameTEpred='PredictedNewData_'+ filesufix +'.xlsx'
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filenameTRpred) as TR_writer:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(filenameTEpred) as TE_writer:

# unrelated code...

sheetName = "no-degree_" + str(_C) + "_" + str(_epsilon) 
# _C and _epsilon are float values
export_excel_TR = delta.to_excel (TR_writer, pathresults+filenameTRpred, index = None, header=True, sheet_name = sheetName) # this line triggers the error
```

Comment: On a more serious note, could you chec, whether you are referencing an actually existing file/path? Otherwise, there really is nothing to open.

Comment: I edited the code with the actual path for saving the files